# Spring Boot @CacheEvict save(Iterable<S> entities);

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, spring-cache

I would like to add caching to my Spring Boot 4 application. As a key I would like to use id (type Long) of my entity, value is my entity.
My repository extends CrudRepository.
I cache data for findOne method:

```
public interface SampleEntityService extends CrudRepository<SampleEntity, Long> {
@Cacheable(key = "#a0", value = "findOne")
SampleEntity findOne(Long id);
```

So I would like to invalidate caches for method save iterable of entities (to be consistent):

```
@CacheEvict(value = FIND_ONE, key = "#entities.id")
<S extends SampleEntity> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);
```

but when I call this method:

```
sampleEntityService.save(ImmutableList.of(entity1));
```

I got an exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 10): Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableList' - maybe not public?
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:375)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.ExpressionEvaluator.key(ExpressionEvaluator.java:115)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:621)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.performCacheEvict(CacheAspectSupport.java:406)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.processCacheEvicts(CacheAspectSupport.java:392)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:362)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:299)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.save(Unknown Source)
at my.springboot.dao.sampleentity.SampleEntityCacheTest.testSampleEntityCaching_saveMany(SampleEntityCacheTest.java:119)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

-How can I fix this EL expression to invalidate all items in the cache which id is in the collection ?
-If this is not possible, how to make this method not supported (without writing specific implementation - I like interface magic) ?

Comment: See this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657881/what-strategies-exist-for-using-spring-cache-on-methods-that-take-an-array-or-co) to which I provided 1 possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use @CacheEvict the way you mentioned (with Iterable).

When using "key" attribute of @CacheEvict, the SpEL should point to a single id of the entity that is to be removed from specified cache(s).

It is not directly mentioned in the docs though (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-evict)