# Putting all returned elements into a Spring-Boot cache using annotations

Tags: java, caching, spring-boot, annotations, spring-cache

Using spring-boot and its caching mechanism, is it possible to automatically store all entities returned as a collection into the cache one by one?

For instance picture the following Repository method:

```
@Query("...")
List<Foo> findFooByBar(Bar bar);
```

I'd like to insert these in a Spring Cache, one by one, meaning there would be N insertions (one for each element in the list) rather than just one (the whole list).

Example:

```
@Query("...")
@CachePut(value = "foos", key = "result.each.id")
List<Foo> findFooByBar(Bar bar);
```

Comment: I've logged an issue in Pivotal's JIRA because from a glance at the source code in `CacheAspectSupport` it seems like this is impossible.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15213

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometime ago, another person asked a similar/related [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657881/what-strategies-exist-for-using-spring-cache-on-methods-that-take-an-array-or-co) and I provided an answer along with an [example](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CachingCollectionElementsIndividuallyWithConcurrentMapTest.java).

As you know, by default, out-of-the-box *Spring* does not handle multiple keys/values in the way that you suggested, though I like your thinking here and your example/UC is valid.

Often times, however, you can achieve what you want using an intermediate solution with just a bit of extra work.  *Spring* is an excellent example of the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and the 2 primary abstractions in [*Spring's Cache Abstraction*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache) is the [Cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) and [CacheManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) interfaces.

Typically, you can pick an existing implementation and "adapt" either the `Cache` or the `CacheManager`, or both, as I have done in my [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657881/what-strategies-exist-for-using-spring-cache-on-methods-that-take-an-array-or-co).

Though not as ideal or convenient, hopefully this will give you some ideas until perhaps [SPR-15213](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15213) is considered (though [maybe not](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15213?focusedCommentId=135223&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-135223)).

Cheers,
John

Comment: Thanks John, you've given me some great ideas to work with.