# How to cache the list of entires based on its primary key using spring caching

Tags: spring, list, caching, spring-boot, spring-cache

I want to cache the response of the repository class which has the following methods:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "books", key="#id")
Book findById(Long Id);

@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "books", key = "#id")
void deleteById(Long id);

@Cacheable(cacheNames = "books", key="#book.id")
Book save(Book book);

@Cacheable("books")
List<Book> findAll();
```

Except the **findAll()** method, others are working as expected.

How to make **findAll()** to populate the **books** cache with **book.id** as key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Cache with collection of items/entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529029/spring-cache-with-collection-of-items-entities)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a customized [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) and [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) implementation for your caching provider (e.g. Ehcache, Redis or Hazelcast).

By default, OOTB, *Spring's Cache Abstraction* does not split up cached method array/collection type return values into separate entries in the targeted cache.  You must handle this yourself.

See my last response for this [nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529029/spring-cache-with-collection-of-items-entities).

Comment: Thanks for the response, it would be better if spring abstraction caching **documentation** has this as a note.