# How to cache a List<Object> in Java such that the elements in list are cached as a single entry each, using Spring Boot provided caching techniques?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

```
@Query(value = "select  student_rid as row_id, student_name as Name from student_data where student_rid=:Student and visibility=true)", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Map<String, String>> findNameAndRowID(@Param("Student") Long Student);
```

I want to cache the list output, but when I am trying to cache the output the whole List is cached as a single cache entry, and because of this, I have to evict this whole cache(list) entry all the time when I either insert/delete even a single record into the database, which is not what I want as it does not serves the purpose of caching. So is there a way we can cache the list elements as a single entries such that I can only evict/update the single record at any insert/delete statement.

I am using Spring Boot, Java 8, and Spring tool suite as IDE.

Comment: Well, the first challenge would be what the key for each entry should be, how you would access them individually and how you'd handle cache misses.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, lets say that I wanted key as a primary key of the table( like the row_id ), since it is unique for the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked multiple times.

1. [How to cache the list of entires based on its primary key using spring caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330052/how-to-cache-the-list-of-entires-based-on-its-primary-key-using-spring-caching)
2. [Spring Cache with collection of items/entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529029/spring-cache-with-collection-of-items-entities)
3. [Putting all returned elements into a Spring-Boot cache using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966690/putting-all-returned-elements-into-a-spring-boot-cache-using-annotations)
4. [What strategies exist for using Spring Cache on methods that take an array or collection parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657881/what-strategies-exist-for-using-spring-cache-on-methods-that-take-an-array-or-co)

The answer is generally the same.

I suspect any 1 of the links will help, but perhaps start with #3.

Answer (score 0):

Your use-case seems a little odd since you seem to already only load a single student and only the name of it so I'll try to create a more meaningful example you could build on.

First a disclaimer though: I'm coming from a JavaEE background, haven't used Spring in a while and didn't have a chance to actually test the quickly cobbled together approach I'll describe here so please take it with a grain of salt.

Let's assume you have the following service:

```
class StudentService {
   @Autowired
   StudentRepository repo;     

   List<Student> loadStudents(someCriteria) {
      return repo.loadStudents(someCriteria);
   }
}
```

To cache each student you could now introduce a new caching service and call it per student. You might be able to put the method into `StudentService` but I'm not sure Spring would then be able to inject the necessary handling code (maybe through more advanced AOP and byte-code manipulation).

A simple version could look like this:

```
class StudentCacheService {
  @CachePut( value = "studentCache", key = "#student.id")
  Student cacheStudent(Student student) {
    return student;
  }
}

class StudentService {
   @Autowired
   StudentRepository repo;     

   @Autowired
   StudentCacheService cacheService;     

   List<Student> loadStudents(someCriteria) {
      List<Student> students = repo.loadStudents(someCriteria);

      //cache each student individually
      students.forEach(s -> cacheService.cacheStudent(s));

      return students;
   }
}
```

Note that there might be more elegant options like handling it in the cache manager etc. but this should get you started.