# Get separate elements with @Cacheable List

Tags: java, spring, caching, hazelcast, spring-cache

I'm using spring cache integration with hazelcast.
I need to get/set(1st call) all the movies list from/to a hazelcast cache map.
I also need to be able to get a specific movie from the cache map.

My problem is that by using List with `@Cacheable`, it returns a single key (`SimpleKey[]`) which holds all the movies objects, instead of adding the key/values individually, so I can then use `@Cacheable` with a key to get a specific map object.

```
@Cacheable(value = MOVIES_CACHE_NAME, unless = "#result==null or #result.isEmpty()")
public List<Movie> getAllMoviesFromCache() {
    log.debug("Going to call getAllMoviesFromCache");

    List<Movie> movies = null;
    MovieListDetailResponse response = getAllMovies(); //gets from db

    if (response != null && response.getMovies() != null) {
        movies = convertMovieListResponseToMovie(response.getMovies());
    }

    log.debug(String.format("Finished getAllMoviesFromCache, got Response %s", response));

    return movies;
}
```

```
@Cacheable(value = MOVIES_CACHE_NAME, key = "{#movieId}", unless = "#result==null")
public Movie getMovieDetailsFromCache(String movieId) {
    Movie movie = null;
    MovieDetailResponse response = getMovie(movieId); //gets from db

    if (response != null && response.getMovie() != null) {
        movie = convertMovieDetailResponseToMovie(response.getMovie());
    }

    log.info(String.format("Movie by MovieId: '%s'. Response: %s", movieId, movie));
    return movie;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784020/how-to-cache-a-listobject-in-java-such-that-the-elements-in-list-are-cached-as) to this similar SO question and specifically have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529029/spring-cache-with-collection-of-items-entities) (#2 from my previous answer).

My answers also share example code on how to implement such logic with *Spring's Cache Abstraction*, see [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CachingCollectionElementsIndividuallyWithConcurrentMapTest.java).