# Is there a way to apply Spring caching functionality for saveAll Or updateAll with Cacheable function, respectively?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache, trending

```
@CachePut(cacheNames = "projectTeams", key = "#projectTeam.id")
public List<ProjectTeam> updateAll(List<ProjectTeam> projectTeam) {
   return projectTeamRepository.save(projectTeam);
}


@Cacheable(cacheNames = "projectTeams", key = "#id")
public List<ProjectTeam> findByIds(ListOfIds<Long> ids) {
log.info("get project team from db");
log.info("projectTeam id " + id);
return projectTeamRepository.findByIds(ids);
}
```

I don't have any idea what i should put in key.
Does spring cache supports SaveAll.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses a [default key generation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key) strategy to derive the key for the cache entry from the caching-enabled (`@Cacheable` or `@CachePut` annotated) service or repository methods based on the arguments to the method.

Of course, you can [customize key generation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key) used by any cache-enabled bean methods by 1) implementing the [`KeyGenerator` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/KeyGenerator.html) and 2) declaring the `KeyGenerator` bean in your caching annotations, like so:

```java
class ListKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

  public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {

    List<?> list = params[0];

    // use the list to generate a (unique) key for the cache entry
    Object generatedKey = ...;

    return generatedKey;
  }
}
```

> NOTE: The `target` is the Spring managed bean containing your `updateAll(..)` and `findByIds(..)` methods. The `Method` ref is the cache-enabled method invoked, such as `updateAll(..)`. And, the array of Object params are the arguments (e.g. the `List`) to the cache-enabled methods.

> TIP: For simplicity and clarity (recommended), you may want to have 2 independent `List`-based `KeyGenerators` since 1 is a `List` of IDs (`Long`-typed; in the finder/query method) and the other is a `List` of `ProjectTeam` instances (in the update).

In configuration, you would declare:

```java
@Configuration
class ApplicationCacheConfiguration {


  @Bean
  KeyGenerator listKeyGenerator() {
    return new ListKeyGenerator();
  }
}
```

You would apply the custom `KeyGenerator` using:

```java
@Service
class ProjectTeamService {

  @CachePut(cacheNames = "projectTeams" keyGenerator = "listKeyGenerator")
  public List<ProjectTeam> updateAll(List<ProjectTeam> projectTeams) {
    // perform any preprocessing steps as necessary
    return this.projectTeamRepository.saveAll(projectTeams);
  }
}
```

> NOTE: See corresponding [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#keyGenerator()) for `@Cacheable` and [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachePut.html#keyGenerator()) for `@CachePut`.

However, you do not necessarily need a custom `KeyGenerator` if you simply rely on Spring's [default key generation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key) strategy as I mentioned to begin with.

Regarding the approach you chose, this will not work since it is trying to use a Spring SpEL expression to access a single element/item (i.e. a single `ProjectTeam` instance) in a `List` of `ProjectTeam` objects. Same applies for the `List` of IDs.

Which element from the `List` do you use? Do you use all elements (which would be difficult to aggregate using SpEL)? What happens if the `List` argument to the cache-enabled method is empty, or worse, `null`?

> TIP: You should review Spring's [SpEL capabilities](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-language-ref) for more details.

These sort of concerns are more appropriately handled in your custom `KeyGenerator` implementation.

You should also be aware that the cached entries for the cache-enabled methods of your Spring managed bean will be (using "default key generation"):

```
cache-enabled method          | cache key         | cache value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
findByIds(:List<Long>)        | List<Long>        | List<ProjectTeam>
updateAll(:List<ProjectTeam>) | List<ProjectTeam> | List<ProjectTeam>
```

If you are expecting the individual elements/items (e.g. either `Long` IDs or `ProjectTeam` instances) of the `Lists` to be broken out and cached individually in separate cache entries, then you are mistaken because this is  NOT how *Spring's Cache Abstraction* works by default.

The reason I mention this is because it is sort of implied by your (attempted) caching configuration as declared in the annotations.

Spring takes the argument(s) to the cache-enabled method (e.g. `@Cacheable` annotated method) and uses that as a key for the cache entry. The return value of the method is used as the value. Since the cache-enabled methods take a `List` and return a `List` then the cache entry key is the `List` argument and the `List` return value is the cache entry value.

As you might imagine, with each different `List` of IDs or `List` of `ProjectTeam` instances requested, your cache memory space is going to fill up fast! That is because if the `List` in each request (cache-enable method) just differs by 1 element, then that is going to constitute a new cache entry in the cache. Depending on how many (different) requests (invocations) your application processes, and the frequency, this could lead to a serious problem (e.g. OOME)!

If you need individual cache entries for individually requested items, then you should have a look at this [SO post from earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237672/spring-cache-all-elements-in-list-separately).

Good luck!

Comment: Looks like a misguided SO moderator (#sigh) deleted the answer to the "SO post from earlier" that I shared. Here are a few of the references I included in that post: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330052/how-to-cache-the-list-of-entires-based-on-its-primary-key-using-spring-caching, 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529029/spring-cache-with-collection-of-items-entities, 3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966690/putting-all-returned-elements-into-a-spring-boot-cache-using-annotations, and...

Comment: 4) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657881/what-strategies-exist-for-using-spring-cache-on-methods-that-take-an-array-or-co