# How to bind parameter for Cacheable annotation in an interface

Tags: spring, interface, crud, spring-cache

I am trying to use Spring-JPA as shown in the below code.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeCrud extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "emp_by_last_name, key = "#lastName")
    List<Employee> findAllByLastName(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
}
```

Since interfaces do not have parameter names (unless compiled with debug info enabled), I am not able fetch the data because of the below exception.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?) Builder[public abstract java.util.List EmployeeCrud.findAllByLastName(java.lang.String)] caches=[emp_by_last_name] | key='#lastName' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:561)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:502)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:389)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
```

Even if I use `@Param` or `@P` annotation, `CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator` is not able to resolve it since it uses `DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer` which internally uses `StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer` and `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer`.
Had it been it would have also used `AnnotationParameterNameDiscoverer`, `@Param` would have been parsed.

What other solutions do we have to make this work without enabling compiler debug info or implementing `EmployeeCrud` interface?

Comment: What happens if you remove key = "#lastName"?

Comment: It will work. There could be a scenario where the expression could be as given below. In this case, it might not work.
`#entity.lastName`

Comment: What scenario do you mean?

Comment: I have mentioned it in my earlier comment. If the expression is `#entity.lastName`, then in that case it might not work.

Comment: but as long as you have dedicated caches this is irelevatn

Comment: I did not get your point. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Easy! Without debug info enabled, you can refer to the parameter by position, such as this...

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "emp_by_last_name, key = "#a0")
List<Employee> findAllByLastName(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
```

See the [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-spel-context) for more details.

Also, because the `@Cacheable` `findAllByLastName(..)` Repository method only has a single argument, then you do not need to explicitly call out the key to store the value (i.e. the method return value, in the case the `List<Employee>`) in the cache ("`emp_by_last_name`"), since by default, *Spring's Cache Abstraction* uses the method parameters of the cacheable method as the key.  See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key).

You should also be mindful of the fact that the cached result (i.e. the key/value) will be the entire List of Employee objects.  The elements of the List will not be cached individually if that is what you are looking for.  If you need this capability then refer to another post I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529029/spring-cache-with-collection-of-items-entities) on more than 1 occassion.

Hope this helps.

Cheers! -John

Comment: I am looking forward to a solution where I can instead use parameter name binding instead of using position like `a0` or `p0`. I understand that if I implement the interface, then parameter name binding will work but is it possible with interfaces?

Comment: Why does it matter how you reference the key?  The value of the key is the value of the method parameter anyway?  Additionally, the `@Param` annotation is a Spring Data annotation.  Why would the core Spring Framework Cache Abstraction know anything about the `@Param` annotation?  At any rate, you could also...

Comment: Implement your own (1 or more), custom `o.s.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator(s)`, which would allow you to inspect the `@Caheable` method, perhaps search for `@Param` annotations on method parameters, etc.  Spring's Cache Abstraction uses the `KeyGenerator` interface as the "strategy" to resolve the key in the cacheable operation.  See here (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L732-L738).  As such, a `ParameterNameDiscoverer` of any kind is not going to help you.

Comment: It does matter how we reference the key. Obviously the value would be the same but `#lastName` is any day more intuitive than `#p0`. Former is more maintainable than latter.

Comment: You are right about KeyGenerator. But implementing key generator for all the keys is something I do not want. If `#lastName` is not possible in a simple way, then the next best solution is `#p0`.

Also had it been that I was able to pass my own `ParameterNameDiscoverer`, then this problem would have been solved. Something like an extended custom parameter name discoverer and in that case I might have passed `AnnotationParameterNameDiscoverer` and there is nothing wrong about that I believe.

Comment: Well, you don't need to implement a `KeyGenerator` for each key; that would be silly!  You can write a reusable `KeyGenerator` that takes a constructor argument or arguments for all the `@Param` value(s) you want to use as your key for the cacheable operation.  Then with that information and using reference to the cacheable `Method` in the `KeyGenerator.generate(..)` callback you can find the method parameters annotated with desired `@Param` annotations and use their values as the key in the cache operation.  ...

Comment: Then you only need declare beans for all the different key combinations using the same `KeyGenerator` class where caching is needed in your application.  If you are not happy with this solution, then I suggest you contribute a PR.  But, you need to abstract enough of the different types in play since, clearly, the Spring Framework's Cache Abstraction cannot know anything about `@Param`.  I leave you at this.

Comment: Thanks John Blum for the help. Will check for the best solution.