# how can I cache list of object in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I have an method called getUserById

```
@Cacheable(value = "Account", key = "#accountId")
public Account getUserById(Long accountId) {
```

and another method called getUserByIds

```
@Cacheable(?????)
public List<Account> getUserByIds(List<Long> accountIds) {
```

how can I cache all account by account id? thanks

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44557156/259889

Comment: You can store the whole result of the method not the individual users (as in the second approach). Also you are probably using an ORM like hibernate and I would strongly suggest to use the 2nd level caching features of that framework instead of this way of caching then.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to specify key for @Cacheable at all

In my case I needed to read from repo a collection and store it in-memory for the following iterations through a list.

```
@Cacheable("users")
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return repository.getUsers();
}
```

Using this method my method returns list from cache every time it is NOT empty INSTEAD of invoking repository.

Thus, for the sake of updating cache I managed to clear it automatically using cron (in my case every 30 seconds to see the difference)

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0,30 * * * * ?")
@CacheEvict(value = "users", allEntries = true)
public void deleteCache() {
  // this method can be empty
}
```

Do not forget to set up @EnableCaching in main class of your Spring Boot Application

**Another way is to use Guava Memoizer** https://www.baeldung.com/guava-memoizer

You can first declare a Supplier

```
private Supplier<Map<String, User>> memoizedSupplier;
```

Then initialise it using some init method, inititalization block or even constructor

```
public void init() {
    memoizedSupplier = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(
                userService::getUsers, USER_CACHE_TTL_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

After that you can easily get cached result while it lasts

```
private Movie getMemoized() {
    return memoizedSupplier.get();
}
```